# Creating Jenkinsfile and plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have never used jenkins or any CI/CD tool before. 
What I want to do is on commit(all/to a specific branch)

1. docker exec into a container
2. cd to a path
3. execute (2/3) scripts with some parameters.

Also, I don't know where to put the scripts? I have them locally right now.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you got jenkins site you can find the basic examples, how to archive what you want https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Comment: Is your jenkins and docker in the same host? What kind of technologies are in your docker? Are your scripts the classic , download, build and deploy?

Comment: I have created a JenkinsFile now after reading the link provided. 
But I dont think it works on custom images. It is only working on images from dockerhub or dockerfile. 
I already have containers running and want to exec into one. Is it possible?

secondly I dont know where to put the scripts that i want to execute in the container. I think they need to go in git repo with jenkinsfile?

Comment: Jenkins and docker are on different host. But for now, im running docker locally and want to test on my machine.  Im using multiple technologies but in this container im using Apache NiFi. My script is a shell script that will run in the nifi cli enviornment and are related to Nifi automation. I mean the cli is invoked from the scripts. Its working locally and on server without jenkins.